# Functional Calculus Inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality, functional-inequalities

When I was solving an olympiad problem, I came out of this hypothetical inequality:

> For bijective $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$, continuous in $[0,1], f(0)=1, f(1)=0$, then we have:
> $$\int_0^1 xf(x)dx\int _0^1xf^{-1}(x)dx\ge \dfrac{2}{9}\left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right)^3$$

Apparently, the equality case is $f(x)=1-x$, or more generally, $f''=0$ (if the continuous condition is not necessary). In fact, there is a more general way to present the inequality. Note that for the region under $y=f(x)$ in $[0,1]$, the $x$-coordinate of centroid of region is determined by $\frac{\int_0^1 xf(x)dx}{\int_0^1 f(x)dx}$, similar for $y$-coordinate. So by this we could rephrase the statement into:

> Given a bounded region $A$ in the first quadrant and the coordinates of its centroid are $(C_x,C_y)$, then $C_xC_y\ge \dfrac{2}{9}Area(A)$.

I am absolutely astonished by this result, but I have no idea how to verify it (maybe functional calculus?) It would be great if anyone could give some idea on this problem, even counterexamples!

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but under the given conditions on $f$ is $\int _0^1xf^{-1}(x)dx = \frac 12 \int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx$.

Comment: @MartinR I also observed that, but it does not give much progress (also the original version looks more symmetrical)

Comment: I do understand the confusion or conflation but "functional calculus" has a well-defined meaning, at the very least in terms of the tag I removed: it applies to a mapping of the type $f \mapsto f(A)$ which assigns to certain functions $f$ an operator $f(A)$ which serves to "apply $f$ to the operator $A$" in a precise sense. This notion appears in spectral theory, especially for self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces. Anyway, sorry for the rambling, and have a nice day/night/whatever time it is for you!

Comment: Bruno is correct